# What is the maximum number of dimensions allowed for an array in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

You can declare a very simple array with 10 elements and use it that way :

```
int myArray[10];
myArray[4] = 3;
std::cout << myArray[4];
```

Or declare a 2d array with 10x100 elements as `int myArray[10][100];`

Even create more complicated 3-d arrays with `int myArray[30][50][70];`

I can even go as far as writing :

```
int complexArray[4][10][8][11][20][3];
complexArray[3][9][5][10][15][3] = 5;
std::cout <<  complexArray[3][9][5][10][15][3];
```

So, **what is the maximum number of dimensions that you can use when declaring an array?**

Comment: It's one, obviously.

Comment: Actually, your second example has a buffer overrun in it. Whoops.

Comment: Why some nub downvote? It's not a bad or wrong question.

Comment: Pretty sure multi lines mean 2 dimensions.

Comment: I'm really curoius: why do you need to know? Because you might be asking the wrong question.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes Can you explain? I can declare multi-dimensionnal arrays. In the memory it will be just a contiguous block of memory, which is, in the end, a one dimension array. But I wanted to know what the standard allowed on dimensions (like Fanael's answer).

Comment: @DeadMG Whoops indeed! Well that's still valid C++, just that it can't run.

Comment: This brings to my mind some interesting related questions. If I have `int a = 0;`, how many times I am allowed to take its address? Is `int ******************** p = &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&a;` valid, for example?

Comment: Why not write a program to find out?  Have your program generate source files with ever-longer array dimensions, then execute the compiler against them and run them.  A good little project to learn the system interfaces for doing that sort of stuff.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The standard recommends the implementations to accept at least 256 (ISO 14882, B.2), but they may support less or more:

> The limits may constrain quantities that include those described below or others. The bracketed number
>   following each quantity is recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these quantities are
>   only guidelines and do not determine compliance.
>
> […]
>
> — Pointer, array, and function declarators (in any combination) modifying an arithmetic, structure, union, or incomplete type in a declaration [256].

It's the same in both C++03 and C++11.

Answer (score 5):

My first post!

For what it is worth, the limit on my system is just 30 dimensions when allocated statically and 19 dimensions when allocated on the stack. System is AMD A10-7700K, 64-bit (8 GB RAM). Compiled on Visual C++ 2013 with default settings.

Note that in order to determine the maximum on your system, use the smallest data type (char) with the smallest dimension size (2). There is no limit when the dimension is 1 since a dimension of 1 (in any dimension) is redundant and does not affect the overall size of the array. It stands to reason that the larger the data type or the larger the size of a dimension, the fewer dimensions you can have. However, I have found that any one (and only one) dimension can be 3, but not 4.

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
   char a[2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2] = {0}; // ok
   char b[2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2] = {0}; // fail!
   static char c[2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2] = {0}; // ok
   static char d[2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2] = {0}; // fail!

}
```

Comment: A dimension of 1 is not redundant, since  `T` and `T[1]` have different semantics.

Comment: The semantics differ but the memory consumption does not. But is there any practical use for a dimension of 1?

Comment: @PeterForrest `typedef struct mpz mpz_t[1];`: gives you a type that you can allocate however you see fit, but can treat like an opaque handle (no need to use `&` whenever you pass it around).

Comment: @a3f That's actually pretty smart. If i'm understanding this right, this allows for statically-allocated opaque types.

Answer (score -4):

The only limit you have when writing arrays is the memory capacity your computer has.

Comment: Incorrect - that is not actually a limit. Thanks to virtual memory and paging, a process can actually address more data than the system has physical memory (albeit slowly). On the other hand, due to memory fragmentation the biggest array a process can allocate may be significantly smaller than its address space.